# How to Save Customized Html widgets data in Drive data table

Tags: google-app-maker

I have created HTML widgets  (Calculator) to calculate per hour manpower effort, On Submit how can I save this data in Drive data table.

Using this data wants to genrate the workflow email.

```html
  <div class="gap10"></div>
<div class="container">             
  <table class="table table-bordered data" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="4"><h3  style="text-align: left;margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;">Technology Design Services</h3></th>
    </tr>
      <tr class="one">
        <th>Service Area</th>
        <th>Per Hour Rate</th>
        <th>Number Of Hours</th>
        <th>Total Rate</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Contact Centre Expert</td>
        <td><div class="form-group num">
<input  name="" type="number" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"id="PerHourRate1"type="text" value="2325" readonly>
</div></td>
        <td><div class="form-group num">
<input  name="" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"value="0" id="rTpe1">
</div></td>
<td><div class="form-group num">
<input  name="" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"value="0" id="rFor1"readonly>
</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Solution Design</td>
        <td><div class="form-group num">
<input  name="" type="number" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"id="PerHourRate2"type="text" value="2762" readonly>
</div></td>
        <td><div class="form-group num">
<input  name="" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"value="0"id="rTpe2">
</div></td>
<td><div class="form-group num">
<input  name="" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"value="0" id="rFor2"readonly>
</div></td>
      </tr>
```

[image: HTML Form]

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using custom HTML vs App Maker widgets to build this table?

Comment: How can I create  same table in app maker

Comment: Can I create same table without using  custom designed table in app maker using  form widgets?

Comment: Hmm... do you want to build a table using multiple Form widgets (https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/data-widgets#form), right?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Model with `ServiceArea`, `PerHourRate`, `NumberOfHours` fields then you can just drop a table on a page (table wizard allows to select which fields should be editable), add column for total rate and set binding for it to `@datasource.item.PerHourRate * @datasource.item.NumberOfHours`. With such setup changes made to `NumberOfHours` field will be automatically saved to database.

**Note:**

If you want to keep `PerHourRate` read only, be sure to implement server side validation for that in [Model Events](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/events).